# AWS DynamoDB session table keeps growing, can't delete expired sessions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-state, aws-sdk

the ASP.NET_SessionState table grows all the time, already at 18GB, not a sign of ever deleting expired sessions.

we have tried to execute DynamoDBSessionStateStore.DeleteExpiredSessions, but it seems to have no effect.

our system is running fine, sessions are created and end-users are not aware of the issue. however, it doesn't make sense the table keeps growing all the time...
we have triple checked permissions/security, everything seems to be in order. we use SDK version 3.1.0. what else remains to be checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your table being over 18 GB, which is quite large (in this context), it does not surprise me that this isn't working after looking at the code for the [DeleteExpiredSessions](https://github.com/aws/aws-dotnet-session-provider/blob/3.1.0.1/src/DynamoDBSessionStateStore.cs#L728) method on GitHub.

Here is the code:

> ```
>     public static void DeleteExpiredSessions(IAmazonDynamoDB dbClient, string tableName)
>     {
>         LogInfo("DeleteExpiredSessions");
>         Table table = Table.LoadTable(dbClient, tableName, DynamoDBEntryConversion.V1);
>
>
>         ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter();
>         filter.AddCondition(ATTRIBUTE_EXPIRES, ScanOperator.LessThan, DateTime.Now);
>
>         ScanOperationConfig config = new ScanOperationConfig();
>         config.AttributesToGet = new List<string> { ATTRIBUTE_SESSION_ID };
>         config.Select = SelectValues.SpecificAttributes;
>         config.Filter = filter;
>
>         DocumentBatchWrite batchWrite = table.CreateBatchWrite();
>         Search search = table.Scan(config);
>
>         do
>         {
>             List<Document> page = search.GetNextSet();
>             foreach (var document in page)
>             {
>                 batchWrite.AddItemToDelete(document);
>             }
>         } while (!search.IsDone);
>
>         batchWrite.Execute();
>     }
> ```

The above algorithm is executed in two parts.  First it performs a `Search` (table scan) using a filter is used to identify all expired records.  These are then added to a `DocumentBatchWrite` request that is executed as the second step.

Since your table is so large the table scan step will take a very, very long time to complete before a single record is deleted.  Basically, the above algorithm is useful for lazy garbage collection on small tables, but does not scale well for large tables.

The best I can tell is that the execution of this is never actually getting past the table scan and you may be consuming all of the read throughput of your table.

---

A possible solution for you would be to run a slightly modified version of the above method on your own.  You would want to call the the `DocumentBatchWrite` inside of the do-while loop so that records will start to be deleted before the table scan is concluded.

That would look like:

> ```
>     public static void DeleteExpiredSessions(IAmazonDynamoDB dbClient, string tableName)
>     {
>         LogInfo("DeleteExpiredSessions");
>         Table table = Table.LoadTable(dbClient, tableName, DynamoDBEntryConversion.V1);
>
>
>         ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter();
>         filter.AddCondition(ATTRIBUTE_EXPIRES, ScanOperator.LessThan, DateTime.Now);
>
>         ScanOperationConfig config = new ScanOperationConfig();
>         config.AttributesToGet = new List<string> { ATTRIBUTE_SESSION_ID };
>         config.Select = SelectValues.SpecificAttributes;
>         config.Filter = filter;
>
>         Search search = table.Scan(config);
>
>         do
>         {
>             // Perform a batch delete for each page returned
>             DocumentBatchWrite batchWrite = table.CreateBatchWrite();
>             List<Document> page = search.GetNextSet();
>             foreach (var document in page)
>             {
>                 batchWrite.AddItemToDelete(document);
>             }
>             batchWrite.Execute();
>         } while (!search.IsDone);
>     }
> ```

*Note: I have not tested the above code, but it is just a simple modification to the open source code so it should work correctly, but would need to be tested to ensure the pagination works correctly on a table whose records are being deleted as it is being scanned.*

Comment: I submitted a pull request to AWS to fix this bug in their code here: https://github.com/aws/aws-dotnet-session-provider/pull/2

Comment: thanks @JaredHatfield, that's very good insight to how things work!!

Comment: We accepted the pull request and pushed out version 3.1.0.2 to NuGet